# Django models: UUID on non-primary-key field not generated in admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have added an `UUIDField` to one of my models. Everything works fine, except for creating objects from the admin panel, where the UUID is not generated automatically. I had to resort to setting the UUID on newly created instances.

Here is the code of my model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

I didn't do anything else anywhere. When I call `User.objects.create(...)`, the instance is created with a uuid, but when I create one in the admin panel, it fails with uuid being null and violating the not-null constraint.

As a workaround, I did this, but it doesn't seem right.

```
class UserAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.uuid = uuid4()
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Is the uuid field present in the form on Admin panel? It so and if you're sending it as empty, that could be the cause, you could be explicitly providing value null for the field

Comment: @OzgurAkcali No, it is not in the form. At least, I didn't add it to the form, I will check if it got added there implicitly. Thanks )

Comment: having the exact same issue... please tell me if there is a solution to it

Answer (score 1):

Change the "editable" parameter of the field to true.

Here is an example:

Before (id will not appear in admin):

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

After (id will appear in admin):

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).